Updating Xamarin.Android Custom View Layout After Updating In Code
I have a Custom View that inherits from GridLayout. I have implemented the standard constructors (by inheriting from the base constructors) and calling the Initialize method that I have implemented. The layout, which includes a RecyclerView & Slider, is inflated in the Initialize method. All components are displayed when I use the view, but the layout is not updated (it just uses the original values in the layout). I'm sure that I just need to call the RequestLayout() and/or Invalidate() methods somewhere at some point (whether it be my custom view, the adapter for the RecyclerView, or somewhere else), but I'm not sure where or when that would be. Any suggestions? Thanks.

instead of describing your code to us, its much more effective to post the actual relevant code
